# how to create a textbox one by one inside the grid using for loop dynamically?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new windows phone, I want to create a textbox one by one inside the grid using for loop dynamically. and i want to access the textboxes using their names to perform some calculations. my code is shown below:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] str = new string[2];
        str[0] = "force";
        str[1] = "force components";
        TextBox[] textbox = new TextBox[2];

       for (int i =0; i <2; i++)
       {
           textbox[i].Text = str[i]; 

            ContentPanel.Children.Add(textbox[i]);
        }
    }
```

the above code shows null reference exception in the line "textbox[i].Text = str[i]".
please, show me the code for clearing this issue. help me. Thank You..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely convinced you're doing this the right way*, but in the absense of any better information I'll directly answer your question...
You're not declaring a new TextBox for each iteration of the loop.  Try this...

```
for (int i =0; i <2; i++)
{
    textbox[i]= new TextBox { Text = str[i] } ; 
    ContentPanel.Children.Add(textbox[i]);
}
```

* Binding to an ItemsControl of some sort would probably be preferable...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what zombiesheep said. You also need to define where they will be drawn. If you do not do that than they will be displayed on top of each other(if you use a grid layout).
So you need to specify there margins, hight and width etc.
I once added buttons to grid control like this and what I did was :

```
button[i].Margin.X= 24+button[i-1].Margin.X;
```

This draws the next button at 24 pixels more on x axis to the one drawn previously.

Comment: Thanks. but i need the button and the textbox in same line inside the listboxitems or inside any other tool, using C# code and without using xaml code. please help me. Thank You.

Comment: I did tell you about the c# code. And you can specify as many items as you want. Well you should have specified you want to use it in listbox... instead of telling that you want to use it in grid control... if its listbox.. Just use databinding and make as many items as you want. As long as they are in the same pattern.